# Disable dates in jquery datepicker according to option selected from dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two datepickers showing startdate and enddate. There is a select box with options:

```
|daily|
|weekly|
|monthly|
|yearly|
```

Suppose the selected option is weekly and date selected in startdate is 2013-03-28 ie; thursday. Then I need to disable all other days in calendar other than thursday in enddate. Likewise if month is selected and startdate is 2013-03-28 then I want to disable all dates other than 28th of every month in enddate. How can I achieve this.

**Script**

```
 $( "#startdate" ).datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        minDate: 0,
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#enddate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });

 $( "#enddate" ).datepicker({
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                minDate: 0,
                changeYear: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                    $( "#startdate" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it this way:

```
$(function() {
    var period = 'weekly';
    var filterDate = function(date) {
        var today = new Date();
        if (period == 'weekly') {
            if (today.getUTCDay() != date.getUTCDay()) {
                return [false, "", ""];                
            }
        } else if (period == 'monthly') {
            if (today.getDate() != date.getDate()) {
                return [false, "", ""];                
            }            
        }
        return [true,"",""];
    };

    $("#period").change(function() {
        period = $(this).val();
    });    
    ...
    $( "#enddate" ).datepicker({
        ...
        beforeShowDay: filterDate
    });
});
```

Here is live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/netme/8GYsx/